# Magento Module GET Requests Not Being Recieved

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

I am creating a module that takes an SKU via a GET requests and returns a JSON object with some of that product's attributes.

My indexController function code looks like this

```
public function pinboardgetitemsAction(){
    $sku = $_GET[sku];

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

    $fullItem = array();

    $fullItem[0] = $product->getName();
    $fullItem[1] = $product->getFormatedPrice();
    $fullItem[2] = $product->getSmallImageUrl();

    echo json_encode($fullItem);

}
```

When I load this request in a browser it correctly returns the JSON object

http://www.jinkou.info/pinboard/index/pinboardgetitems?sku=50065

However when I do an AJAX request (I am using jQuery) $sku is not set and an Fatal error is thrown.

The easiest way to see this behaviour is by using http://hurl.it

Comment: Typo? `$sku = $_GET[sku];` should be `$sku = $_GET['sku'];`

Comment: Kind of a typo, tried it with and without quotes, both worked in browser and not with hurl.it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from my typo comment, the appropriate way to access params is through the request object:

```
$sku = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sku');
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this function.  I have swapped the "$sku = $_GET[sku];" with the line that you provided but still the same issue.

Comment: Then you have an issue with data.

Comment: Which data do you mean?  $sku is not being set on certain clients which would indicate something other than the data

Answer (score 0):

benmarks wrote right answer.

Sorry for offtop, but the next code:

```
echo json_encode($fullItem);
```

is not proper. You should to set json content type in the header and set json body in the response body:

```
/** @var $helper Mage_Core_Helper_Data */
$helper = Mage::helper('core');
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
$this->getResponse()->setBody($helper->jsonEncode($fullItem);
```

Comment: thanks, out of interest does this provide any performance improvements?

Comment: i think no, but use 'echo' in the controller's method is a bad logic. You should set body to the response object.